# How do i fix my spawning script from randomly stopping the spawning of enemies?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple script that is supposed to spawn zombies with time delays that can be inputted. The script seems to work fine however, after I move my character for a while, the gameobject which is running the script stops spawning zombies.If my character stands still, the zombies will continue to spawn. The red arrow is pointing to the gameObject that is spawning the zombies.

[image: screenshot 1]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class spawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject zombie;
    public float delayTime = 4f;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        var obj = Instantiate(zombie, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);
        StartCoroutine(Start());
    }
}
```

Scene setup is as follows:

[image: screenshot 2]
[image: screenshot 3]
[image: screenshot 4]
[image: screenshot 5]

Comment: Could maybe controlling the player freeze the application? You say it only happens when the player moves.

Answer (score 1):

First separate your spawning function from your Start function to avoid confusion.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawningRoutine());
}
```

Then you want your coroutine to continue spawning forever? You need a loop inside the coroutine. In the example below I made an infinite loop but you could have a counter for the number of zombies you want for example.

```
IEnumerator SpawningRoutine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        var obj = Instantiate(zombie, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayTime);
    }
}
```

Lastly remember to put this spawn script on an object that is not a zombie. Have a separate spawn object with only this script on it. You probably do this already.

Edit in response to logging:

Add a logging script to your zombie prefab like so:

```
private static int zombieCounter = 0;
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Number of zombies spawned so far: " + zombieCounter++);
}
```

Comment: i still seem to have the problem

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your zombie prefab and player with all their scripts visible? There must be something else in the scene that interferes with your spawner,

Comment: Cool thanks. Does your PlayerMove scripts reference the Spawner? Or do you have any keyboard handling code that may affect the spawner?

Comment: i think it actually has something to do more with my shooting scripts maybe. because when i shoot it stops spawning shortly after

Comment: Cool that is a good clue. Can you post your shooting script in the question?

Comment: How does isFiring get controlled? How does it go from false to true and vice versa?

Comment: I also want to ask to please add this extra information on the original question so that new readers can also help you.

Comment: if the user left clicks their mouse isFiring gets set to True until the left mouse button is released

Comment: Add some logging to your spawn script that increments a counter every time it spawns. Log that counter. Maybe they get spawned but they somehow die immediately.

Comment: I added a code snippet to the answer. Add a new script to your zombie prefab. This code will log 1 for the first zombie then 2 for the next and so on. The idea is that you can see if the zombies stop spawning and if maybe they spawn but they get destroyed right away.

Comment: the zombies just stop spawning

Comment: Okay it's a mysterious one. I will continue to help you later through the private chat.

Comment: I think I figured it out. As the game is running when I shoot, the gameobject (zombie) for some reason disappears from the script. so the spawner has nothing to spawn. I am not sure why this is happening though.

Comment: Is your zombie a prefab or an object that is already in the scene when the game starts? If it is already in the scene it is possible to kill the source of your spawner.

Comment: @Reasurria what is the logging for? If it's inside the zombie, it'll simply say "Number of zombies spawned so far: 0" every time a zombie spawns. Not sure if that was your desired output..

Comment: @Alox It's static. It will count upwards.

Comment: @Reasurria sorry about that, I didn't know that was how it worked... but it should probably do a preincrementation correct? As to display the current amount of zombies spawned. (not that it really matters)

Comment: @Alox My mistake. You are correct this will start counting at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use coroutine for that, InvokeRepeating should be good enough. Also make sure your zombie prefab is private so it doesn't get replaced by other scripts

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject zombie;
float waitBeforeFirstSpawn = 0f;
float delayTime = 4f;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnZombie", waitBeforeFirstSpawn, delayTime);
}

void SpawnZombie()
{
    GameObject zombieGO = Instantiate(zombie, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
}
```

Comment: zombie prefab is public, so he can access it in the inspector

Comment: @DávidFlorek [SerializeField] will make private fields accessible through the editor.

Comment: @DávidFlorek Yes but from what he said it seem like he is overriding his zombie prefab with null somewhere outside the spawning script so it will fix it for him. Also - as Reasurria said - he can set [SerializeField] to access it from inspector

Comment: I think he put an instance of zombie instead of a prefab. So when he shoots and kills the instance it gets destroyed and removed from the spawning script.

Comment: That might be the case too.

Comment: Thats exactly what it was I figured it out this morning thanks!